# Karaf OSGi camel-hdfs2

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, hdfs, karaf

I'm having a tough time getting the camel-hdfs2 component to function as expected in a Karaf 4.0 OSGi container.  It's a very simple camel route that is reading files from HDFS and simply writing the file name to a new file in /tmp.

I've got it to work outside of the Karaf OSGi container just by running the main method (included below), but when I try and start it up in Karaf, I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem not found
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1882)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2298)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2311)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:90)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2350)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2332)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:369)
 at cas.example.camel_hdfs.LocalRouteBuilder.start(LocalRouteBuilder.java:83)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_51]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_51]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_51]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)[:1.8.0_51]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:231)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:39)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:624)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:508)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:149)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:315)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:127)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:871)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:838)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:850)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:419)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:376)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialize(BundleComponentActivator.java:172)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.<init>(BundleComponentActivator.java:120)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:258)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$000(Activator.java:45)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:185)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:479)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:414)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:443)[23:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
 at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:913)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.0.1.jar:]
 at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:834)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.0.1.jar:]
 at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:516)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.0.1.jar:]
 at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4544)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.0.1.jar:]
 at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2166)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.0.1.jar:]
 at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.0.1.jar:]
 at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1245)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
 at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1217)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
 at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1207)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
 at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:504)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
 at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:358)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
 at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:310)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem not found
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1788)
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1880)
... 46 more
```

I know the class is available in the runtime (59 was my bundle).  In it I'm defining a camel route in a RouteBuilder (class shown below) that will make use of the camel-hdfs component:

```
 karaf@root()> list 59
 START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
 ID | State  | Lvl | Version        | Name
 ---------------------------------------------------
 59 | Active |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | cas-camel-hdfs
 karaf@root()> bundle:classes 59 | grep LocalFileSystem
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/LocalFileSystem.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/LocalFileSystemConfigKeys.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem$1.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem.class
 karaf@root()>
```

Here is my RouteBuilder/Activator:

```
package cas.example.camel_hdfs;

import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Activate;
import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Component;
import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Deactivate;

@Component
public class LocalRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    private final String hdfsHost;
    private final String path;
    private static final String MARKED_SUFFIX = "ingested";

    /**
     * If running in OSGI...
     */
    private CamelContext cContext = null;

    public LocalRouteBuilder() {
        this("10.10.1.20", "/user/cloud-user/cas-docs", "cloud-user");
    }

    /**
     * If you use this constructor, make sure the HADOOP_USER_NAME is set via a
     * jvm property.
     * 
     * @param hdfsHost
     * @param path
     */
    public LocalRouteBuilder(final String hdfsHost, final String path) {
        this(hdfsHost, path, null);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param hdfsHost
     * @param path
     * @param userName
     */
    public LocalRouteBuilder(final String hdfsHost, final String path, final String userName) {
        this.cContext = this.getContext();
        this.hdfsHost = hdfsHost;
        this.path = path;
        if (userName != null) {
            System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", userName);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("hdfs2://" + hdfsHost + path + "?delay=5000&chunkSize=4096&connectOnStartup=true&readSuffix=" + MARKED_SUFFIX)

        .setBody(simple(path + "/${header[CamelFileName]}." + MARKED_SUFFIX))

        .to("log:cas.example.camel_hdfs.BasicRouteBuilder")

        .to("file:/tmp/RECEIVED")

        .stop().end();

    }

    @Activate
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.setClass("fs.file.impl", LocalFileSystem.class, FileSystem.class);
        conf.setClass("fs.hdfs.impl", DistributedFileSystem.class, FileSystem.class);
        FileSystem.get(URI.create("file:///"), conf);
        FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://10.10.1.20:9000/"), conf);

        if (cContext != null) {
            cContext.stop();
            cContext = null;
        }
        // cContext = new OsgiDefaultCamelContext(context);
        cContext.addRoutes(this);
        cContext.start();
        cContext.startAllRoutes();
    }

    @Deactivate
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Stopping hdfs camel bundle");
        if (cContext != null) {
            cContext.stop();
            cContext = null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Main m = new Main();
            m.addRouteBuilder(new LocalRouteBuilder("10.10.1.20", "/user/cloud-user/cas-docs", "cloud-user"));
            m.enableHangupSupport();
            m.enableTrace();
            m.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

}
```

Just in case it helps, here is bundle list:

```
karaf@root()> list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
 ID | State    | Lvl | Version            | Name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 58 | Active   |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT     | karaf-feature-export
 59 | Active   |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT     | cas-camel-hdfs
 60 | Active   |  80 | 2.4.0.201411031534 | bndlib
 61 | Active   |  80 | 2.15.2             | camel-blueprint
 62 | Active   |  80 | 2.15.2             | camel-catalog
 63 | Active   |  80 | 2.15.2             | camel-commands-core
 64 | Active   |  80 | 2.15.2             | camel-core
 65 | Active   |  80 | 2.15.2             | camel-spring
 66 | Active   |  80 | 2.15.2             | camel-karaf-commands
 67 | Active   |  80 | 1.1.1              | geronimo-jta_1.1_spec
 72 | Active   |  80 | 2.2.6.1            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jaxb-impl
 84 | Active   |  80 | 3.1.4              | Stax2 API
 85 | Active   |  80 | 4.4.1              | Woodstox XML-processor
 86 | Active   |  80 | 2.15.2             | camel-core-osgi
 87 | Active   |  80 | 18.0.0             | Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java
 88 | Active   |  80 | 2.6.1              | Protocol Buffer Java API
 89 | Active   |  80 | 1.9.12             | Jackson JSON processor
 90 | Active   |  80 | 1.9.12             | Data mapper for Jackson JSON processor
 91 | Active   |  80 | 2.15.2             | camel-hdfs2
 92 | Active   |  80 | 1.2                | Commons CLI
 93 | Active   |  80 | 1.10.0             | Apache Commons Codec
 94 | Active   |  80 | 3.2.1              | Commons Collections
 95 | Active   |  80 | 1.5.0              | Commons Compress
 96 | Active   |  80 | 1.9.0              | Commons Configuration
 97 | Active   |  80 | 2.4.0              | Commons IO
 98 | Active   |  80 | 2.6                | Commons Lang
 99 | Active   |  80 | 3.3.0              | Apache Commons Math
100 | Active   |  80 | 3.3.0              | Commons Net
101 | Active   |  80 | 3.4.6              | ZooKeeper Bundle
102 | Active   |  80 | 1.7.7.1            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: avro
103 | Active   |  80 | 3.1.0.7            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: commons-httpclient
104 | Active   |  80 | 3.0.0.1            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: guice
105 | Active   |  80 | 2.3.0.2            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: hadoop-client
106 | Active   |  80 | 0.1.51.1           | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jsch
107 | Active   |  80 | 2.6.0.1            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: paranamer
108 | Active   |  80 | 0.52.0.1           | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: xmlenc
109 | Active   |  80 | 1.2.0.5            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: xmlresolver
110 | Active   |  80 | 3.9.6.Final        | Netty
111 | Resolved |  80 | 1.1.0.1            | Snappy for Java
karaf@root()>
```

Thanks for your help!

-Ben

EDIT:

So, I added the bundle headers for my custom bundle (I did a karaf clean, so the bundle id changed from 39 to 109).

```
karaf@root()> bundle:headers 109

cas-camel-hdfs (109)
--------------------
Bnd-LastModified = 1440904390702
Build-Jdk = 1.8.0_51
Built-By = bdgould
Created-By = Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Manifest-Version = 1.0
Service-Component = OSGI-INF/cas.example.camel_hdfs.Hdfs2RouteBuilder.xml,OSGI-INF/cas.example.camel_hdfs.SimpleRouteBuilder.xml
Tool = Bnd-2.4.1.201501161923

Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2
Bundle-Name = cas-camel-hdfs
Bundle-SymbolicName = com.inovexcorp.cas_cas-camel-hdfs
Bundle-Version = 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT

Require-Capability = 
    osgi.ee;filter:=(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))

DynamicImport-Package = 
    *
Export-Package = 
    cas.example.camel_hdfs;uses:="org.apache.camel.builder,org.osgi.framework";version=0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
Import-Package = 
    org.apache.camel;version="[2.15,3)",
    org.apache.camel.builder;version="[2.15,3)",
    org.apache.camel.main;version="[2.15,3)",
    org.apache.camel.model;version="[2.15,3)",
    org.apache.hadoop.conf,
    org.apache.hadoop.fs,
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs,
    org.osgi.framework;version="[1.6,2)",
    org.apache.camel.component.hdfs2;version="[2.15,3)"
```

I'm still not sure why it can't find the LocalFileSystem class, as it's definitely exported from:

```
102 | Active    |  80 | 2.3.0.2            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: hadoop-client
```

This is the hadoop bundle installed as part of the camel-hdfs2 feature.

EDIT 2:
Hmm, I'm actually not sure why the bundle:classes is showing me all of those classes.  I just opened up my JAR, and I'm seeing this:

```
" zip.vim version v27
" Browsing zipfile /opt/apache-karaf-4.0.1/deploy/cas-camel-hdfs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
" Select a file with cursor and press ENTER

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.inovexcorp.cas/
META-INF/maven/com.inovexcorp.cas/cas-camel-hdfs/
META-INF/maven/com.inovexcorp.cas/cas-camel-hdfs/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/com.inovexcorp.cas/cas-camel-hdfs/pom.xml
META-INF/services/
META-INF/services/org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
OSGI-INF/
OSGI-INF/cas.example.camel_hdfs.Hdfs2RouteBuilder.xml
OSGI-INF/cas.example.camel_hdfs.SimpleRouteBuilder.xml
cas/
cas/example/
cas/example/camel_hdfs/
cas/example/camel_hdfs/Hdfs2RouteBuilder.class
cas/example/camel_hdfs/SimpleRouteBuilder.class
core-default.xml
hdfs-default.xml
log4j.xml
```

The classes listed in Karaf don't seem to match what's actually in the JAR (but it must be seeing what classes my bundle is referencing?).  Here is my POM, just in case it helps:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.inovexcorp.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-camel-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Example Camel-HDFS Integration</name>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <camel.version>2.15.2</camel.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-hdfs2</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency><!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> <artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId> 
            <version>${camel.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
            <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/ -->
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}_${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Import-Package>org.apache.camel.component.hdfs2,*;resolution:=required</Import-Package>
                        <Service-Component>*</Service-Component>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a classic Import-Package/Export-Package issue. 
Does your bundle 59 that obviously contain the class in question actually export it?

```
Export-Package: org.apache.hadoop.fs
```

After the Update: 
Obviously you import the right packages, but according to your listing

```
59 | Active |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | cas-camel-hdfs
karaf@root()> bundle:classes 59 | grep LocalFileSystem
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/LocalFileSystem.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/LocalFileSystemConfigKeys.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem$1.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.class
 org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem.class
```

your own bundle also contains those classes, so make sure you don't package them along. 
Most likely your dependency to the *org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client* is marked as compile dependency in your pom.

Comment: So, 59 is actually my bundle that is going to Import-Package.  I'll update my question a bit to be more clear.  My bundle is making use of the camel-hdfs feature bundles, and importing what I think are the necessary bundles.

Comment: capabilities 102
karaf@root()> capabilities 102
org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client [102] provides:
...
osgi.wiring.package; org.apache.hadoop.fs 2.3.0 required by:
   com.inovexcorp.cas_cas-camel-hdfs [109]
   org.apache.camel.camel-hdfs2 [88]
...

Comment: I'm actually not sure why the karaf bundle:classes is showing those classes (unless it's actually looking at all the classes my bundle is referencing).  I've updated the question with both my POM and a view of what's in my JAR (through vim).  Thanks -Ben